# Sum of complex numbers $z_k=\exp{\Big(ik\varphi\Big)}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Show that 
$$\sum_{k=-j}^jz_k=\sum_k\exp{\Big(ik\varphi\Big)}=\frac{\sin{\varphi(j+\frac{1}{2})}}{\sin{\frac{\varphi}{2}}}.$$
I see that $\sum_kz_k=1+2\sum_{k=1}^j\cos{k\varphi}$.

**EDIT**
i write my attempt: the initial sum can be expressed like 
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^je^{ik\varphi}+\sum_{k=1}^je^{-ik\varphi}$$
and then the two sums became 
$$\frac{1+e^{i\varphi(j+1)}}{1-e^{i\varphi}}$$
and
$$\frac{1+e^{-i\varphi(j+1)}}{1-e^{-i\varphi}}$$

Comment: Hint: geometric sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start on the right side. $$\sin\phi(j+(1/2))={e^{i\phi(j+(1/2))}-e^{-i\phi(j+(1/2))}\over2i},\quad\sin(\phi/2)={e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2}\over2i}$$ so $${\sin\phi(j+(1/2))\over\sin(\phi/2)}={e^{i\phi(j+(1/2))}-e^{-i\phi(j+(1/2))}\over e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2}}$$ Now let's look at $$(e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2})\sum_{k=-j}^j e^{ik\phi}$$ Everything cancels except $$e^{i\phi/2}e^{ij\phi}-e^{-i\phi/2}e^{-ij\phi}$$ So $$\sum_{k=-j}^j e^{ik\phi}={e^{i\phi(j+(1/2))}-e^{-i\phi(j+(1/2))}\over e^{i\phi/2}-e^{-i\phi/2}}$$ and we're done.